# Can !Sub be applied to a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a `String` parameter that contains multiple accounts: `"000000000000,111111111111,222222222222"`. I need to `!Split` it and apply `!Sub` to get a list of `arn:aws:iam::${Account}:root` for each `Account`.

The idea is to get:

```json
"Principal": {
  "AWS": [
    "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root",
    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root",
    "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root"
  ]
}
```

I know that I can do it like this:

```yaml
Principal:
  AWS: 
  - !Sub
    - "arn:aws:iam::${Account}:root"
    - Account: !Select [0, !Split [",", !Ref Accounts]]
  - !Sub
    - "arn:aws:iam::${Account}:root"
    - Account: !Select [1, !Split [",", !Ref Accounts]]
  - !Sub
    - "arn:aws:iam::${Account}:root"
    - Account: !Select [2, !Split [",", !Ref Accounts]]
```

But that's not dynamic.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No, unless you develop macro for that.

Comment: @Marcin Could you please provide an example of a macro that would help in this case?

Comment: I would suggest trying to do it yourself, and if you get issues, make new question with the macro code.